# Run multiple lines in a .bat file and each line should wait previus to finish

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file(with more than 50 line) that runs automation tests over the night. I want to get rid of lines with ping and somehaw to make commands run each one after previous

--**First line execute the test**

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\ide\mstest.exe"/testcontainer:c:\deploy\AutomationTest\273\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.dll /resultsfile:AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx

--**Second line wait for 300 seconds untill the test is done**

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 300 >null

-- **third line will publish the test**

start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tcm" run /publish /suiteid:906 /configid:2 /resultowner:"USer" /resultsfile:"c:\temp\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx" /collection:http://testenvironment:8080/tfs/Test/teamproject:Test

--**Again wait until it's Published**
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 >null

--**Then the result file will bw modev to another location**

start "" move /y "c:\temp\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx" "c:\temp\Processed\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation%RANDOM%.trx"

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 >null

And these steps are done for each test (and are a lot of tests). 
Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation: use either

```
start "" /B /WAIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\ide\mstest.exe"/testcontainer:c:\deploy\AutomationTest\273\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.dll /resultsfile:AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx
start "" /B /WAIT "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tcm" run /publish /suiteid:906 /configid:2 /resultowner:"USer" /resultsfile:"c:\temp\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx" /collection:http://testenvironment:8080/tfs/Test/teamproject:Test
move /y "c:\temp\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx" "c:\temp\Processed\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation%RANDOM%.trx"
:: etc.
```

or, you could omit all the `start "" /B /WAIT` and use simply

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\ide\mstest.exe"/testcontainer:c:\deploy\AutomationTest\273\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.dll /resultsfile:AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tcm" run /publish /suiteid:906 /configid:2 /resultowner:"USer" /resultsfile:"c:\temp\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx" /collection:http://testenvironment:8080/tfs/Test/teamproject:Test
move /y "c:\temp\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation.trx" "c:\temp\Processed\AutomationMedical-AddRadiation%RANDOM%.trx"
:: etc.
```

Explanation: Combining my answers to

- [Have the command prompt launch an application and block until it is closed](https://superuser.com/a/908744/376602)
- [Start /wait /b not exiting program when there is an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931915/3439404),

Read more about `start`: [Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx).

**Note** `move` is an internal command; for an internal cmd command or a batch file, `/WAIT` switch causes running `CMD /K`.

Hence, `move /y source destination` is equivalent, with respect to `/B` and `/WAIT` switches combination, to

```
start "" /B /WAIT move /y source destination^&exit /B
```

Note `^&exit /B` and note escaped `&` here...

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ, it worked. i used start "" /B /WAIT